# How to go about proving an algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof

The algorithm (called as rmax(1,n)) finds the maximum of a list of numbers contained in an array S[1..n].

```
rmax(x, y)
// return maximum in S[x..y]
if y − x ≤ 1
then return maximum(S[x], S[y])
else max1 ← rmax(x, [x+y]/2)
     max2 ← rmax([x+y]/2 + 1, y)
     return maximum(max1, max2)
```

How would I go about arguing that the algorithm is correct?

Comment: I was going to give a big long answer but realized I didn't quite remember everything perfectly. Take a look at Horae logic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic. The other trick is to ensure that your arguments are less than your input by some certain well founded ordering and then using something like well founded induction you get to assume that the recursive call did what you expected it to and us this fact in the parts of the proof after the call.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: formulate an invariant, which is easy here (it's the hypothesis applied to the recursive calls). Which proof method do you use to prove claims about recursions?

Answer (score 2):

To prove the correctness, we have to prove actually the function
`rmax(x,y)` returns the the maximum number with index between `x` and
`y` in the array `S[1..n]`, provided the hypothesis: `1≤x≤y≤n`.

There is a semantic technique that often works nicely for recursively
defined functions such as this one.

Your function can be defined as the least fixed-point of a functional:

```
F = λ rmax, x, y. if y-x≤1 then max(S[x],S[y]) else
                  else max(rmax(x,(x+y)/2), rmax((x+y)/2+1,y))
```

I have changed a bit the style, for convenience. You note that `F` is a
function of 3 arguments, and you original function `rmax` is defined
as its least fixpoint in the semantic domain. Also, here `rmax` is a local name for the first argument of `F`. I could replace it by any other name (alpha conversion). I kept `rmax` only for readability.

Now, the way you prove correctness is by checking that this
functionnal preserves correctness when it is applied to a function
`foo` that is correct, when it is defined (it is undefined for example
if it does not terminate, but being defined is actually a formal
semantic property).

That is, you only have to check that if the function `foo(x,y)` is correct, then
the function `F(foo)` is also correct.

```
F(foo) = λ x, y. if y-x≤1 then max(S[x],S[y]) else
                 else max(foo(x,(x+y)/2), foo((x+y)/2+1,y))
```

When `y-x≤1`, we know that either `x=y` or `x=y-1`, since by
hypothesis `1≤x≤y`. In both cases we see that `max(S[x],S[y])` is the
right answer.

Otherwise, we see that `1≤x≤(x+y)/2≤n` and `1≤(x+y)/2+1≤y≤n`. Hence the
hypothesis is verified for the two calls to the function `foo`. So,
since the function `foo` is correct by hypothesis, each call (when
giving a defined result) returns the maximum array value between the
bound given by its parameters (if it is defined). Since both ranges
cover the range between `x` and `y`, the maximum of these two values
is the maximum value between `x` and `y`.

Note that there is no base case in this recursion. The reason is that
it starts using with the totally undefined function $\bot$ (read "bottom"), which is
thus always correct when it is defined.

Note that this does not prove termination of the algorithm. But you get that easily by induction.

**Some further explanations.**

This proof is in a way very similar to the proof suggested by Yuval
Filmus. It is not too surprising as they are both supposed to prove
the same result. However they are quite different in spirit. Yuval's
proof is a recursion on the steps of an actual interpretation of the
program (operational semantics). The proof I am proposing is by
recursion on the structure of the program code seen as an infinite
program defined as the limit of an infinite sequence of finite program
(denotational semantics). It assumes continuity properties (so that
passing to the limit makes sense), which are verified for usual
computing operations and predicates.

The former proof is on the use of the program, while the latter is on its structure.

Comment: This may seem a bit long, but that is because I went into many explanatory details. The proof is actually only the two paragraphs following `F(foo) = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove the correctness of the algorithm is by induction on $y-x$. First you have to state your induction hypothesis carefully: if $1 \leq x \leq y \leq n$ then $\mathrm{rmax}(x,y)$ returns the maximum of $S[x],\ldots,S[y]$. When $y-x \leq 1$, you prove it directly. When $y-x \geq 2$, then $[x+y]/2-x < y-x$ and $y-([x+y]/2+1) < y-x$, and so the induction hypothesis applies to the recursive calls, and from that you can complete the proof. Finally, when $x=1$ and $y=n$, the induction hypothesis implies that the maximum of the entire array is returned.

As Jake mentions, if you want to do this really formally, you'll have to use a more formal framework such as Hoare logic. But usually these frameworks aren't used in earnest, and are best left to computers to deal with.

Comment: I still don't really understand.If the array let's say, contained 3 elements - 1,2, and 3, what would happen?
Would you test 1 and 2, then 1 and 3, then 2 and 3?

Comment: Try drawing up the recursion tree and see what happens. In this particular case, the function first computes $\mathrm{rmax}(1,2) = \max(S[1],S[2])$, then $\mathrm{rmax}(3,3) = \max(S[3],S[3])$, and finally $\mathrm{rmax}(1,3) = \max(\mathrm{rmax}(1,2),\mathrm{rmax}(3,3))$.

Comment: Make sure you understand the code. This is the first step toward proving that it works.

Comment: This is what I needed to clatify. Thanks! Question:
Why would it would it be in that order?

Comment: That's a question for you. If you understand the semantics of the code, you should be able to execute it and come up with the same answer.